# Laravel - Eloquent query to display Quiz Result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write a query in my controller to display Quiz result for students.  I have these tables

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quizz_question` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `question_code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `answer1` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `answer2` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `answer3` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `answer4` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `topic` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `correct_answer` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quizz_attempt` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_code` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NULL,
  `question_code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

The two tables became these two model classes: QuizzQuestion and QuizAttempt.

In quizz_attempt, if a student select an answer (answer), it will take answer and question_code in quizz_attempt and compare with quizz_question.

1. quizz_attempt.answer = 1 then it will choose the content in answer1 as correct answer
2. quizz_attempt.answer = 2 then it will choose the content in answer2 as correct answer
3. quizz_attempt.answer = 3 then it will choose the content in answer3 as correct answer
4. quizz_attempt.answer = 4 then it will choose the content in answer4 as correct answer

   ```
   public function gameQualifiers(Request $request)
   {       
   $revenuedetails = DB::table('quizz_attempt as g')
   ->select(
      'g.student_code', 
      'g.answer'             
   )
   ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC'); 
   }
   ```

I know I need to join the two tables for the result. I started the code in my controller, but don't know how to complete it. i want to write a query to display list of students who choose correct answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quiz attempt should have the `quizz_question_id` as a Foreign Key. This will make it easier down the line to have the two connected.

You can set up two models to match your database tables: QuizzQuestion and QuizzAttempt. You can set up Foreign Keys like so:

QuizzAttempt.php

```
public function quizzQuestion()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\QuizzQuestion');
}
```

And QuizzQuestion.php

```
public function quizzAttempts()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\QuizzQuestion');
}
```

So now, you want to get all of the attempts where the answer is correct - you are looking at an instance of QuizzQuestion, e.g.

```
$question = QuizzQuestion::find(1); // first question

$correctResults = QuizzAttempts::where('quizz_question_id', $question->id)
    ->where('answer', $question->correct_answer)
    ->pluck('student_code');`
```

Now you have all the student codes of the students that got the correct answers.

*** Update

If you cannot change the structure of the tables, you can run the following query:

```
// 1) find the question you want the answers for
$question = QuizzQuestion::find(1);

// 2) retrieve the correct results
$correctResults = QuizzAttempts::where('question_code', $question->question_code)
    ->where('answer', $question->correct_answer)
    ->pluck('student_code');`
```

Comment: I really appreciate what you have done. But I met that table structure there which  I cannt change. Kindly use the table structure. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer @user11352561. It's a shame that you cannot change the structure as a relational database can provide many advantages.